# Shell script (mac): How to download files from a directory using wget and regular expression?

Tags: bash, image, shell, download, wget

I'm trying to download images (.jpg) from web folder using wget. I want to download only images, which have a certain sentences in file name. This works fine

```
wget -r -nd -A .jpg http://www.examplewebsite.com/folder/
```

but I like to include a sentence eg. "john". I tried

```
wget -r -nd -A .jpg '*john*' http://www.examplewebsite.com/folder/
```

with no success. Any ideas how to proceed? Could this be implemented into a shell script (bash shell). I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.1.

Comment: not an SO more of a serverfault or superuser

Comment: Do you want all the pages with john in the page name, or all the pages with john in the text.

Comment: I want to download files from that page (or web folder) which have "john" in a file name. eg. picture_of_john.jpg and johns_picture.jpg

Comment: Hello quick free porn! Shahmir is right in that it's less of a Stack Overflow question and will probably get closed unless changed. Hint: Ask about a shell script to do this. P.S. This can't be done without a list of the images you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer depends on whether you can get a directory listing from the webserver. If you can, you can save that HTML listing, extract the links, filter the list of links for ones that match your criterion, and then pass that filtered list to curl or wget.

If you can't get a list in that way, you need to generate a list in some other way, which probably will be manual. (I'm assuming the only access you have to this server is over http.)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
wget -r -nd -A '*john*.jpg' http://www.examplewebsite.com/folder/
```

From the man:

```
Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of
acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.
```